# Select all rows within a range using IF condition in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate **Median of a Column A** based on 2 criteria from other columns B and C. Condition for criteria in B and C are in cells H1 and E6 respectively, which contain a list of values.

I am using the following formula to calculate median based on criterias

```
= MEDIAN(IF((TableName[[Column B]:[Column B]]= $H$1)*(TableName[[Column C ]:[Column C]]= $E$6), 
  TableName [[Column A]:[Column A]]))
```

I would like to not consider the condition in Column C if the input in E6 is "ALL". In other words, I am looking for a solution to **consider all values in Column C** IF the input in E6 is **"ALL"**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
RV

Answer (score 1):

Add another IF:

```
= MEDIAN(IF((TableName[[Column B]:[Column B]]= $H$1)*(IF($E$6 = "ALL",TRUE,TableName[[Column C ]:[Column C]]= $E$6)), TableName [[Column A]:[Column A]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. @Scott. It saved my day 